# Passing a URL to a cell, but URL is zero when there

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, core-data, uitableview

I have a app where when a user takes a video, it saves the video url to core data and then creates a thumbnail image and adds it to a UITableView, which works great. It also should retrieve the URL that matches the thumbnail for each cell but this is not working. My problem is that for some reason, the url is not being passed from the view controller where it is being recorded to the cell. I have no idea what is happening because the url is fine in the view controller and working correctly but when I pass it with this line, `cell.finalURL = self.finalURL;` it is null in the cell.

Here is where I pass it to the cell:

```
cell.finalURL = self.finalURL;
NSLog(@"here is the URl in the cell: %@", [cell.finalURL absoluteString]);
```

Here is where the url is retrieved from core data (in cellForRowAtIndexPath):

```
NSData *stringData = feed.urlString;
self.stringForURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:stringData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
self.stringForURL = [self.stringForURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
self.finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.stringForURL];
```

And here is where in the cell, it is passed to the next view controller (inside the cell, but because the url is not being passed to the cell correctly, it doesn't have a chance of working):

```
-(void) setUpURL {

NSLog(@"Here is the URL in the real cell: %@", [self.finalURL absoluteString]);
DetailsViewController *detailsViewController = [[DetailsViewController alloc] init];
detailsViewController.finalURL = self.finalURL;
NSLog(@"Here is the URL for the video, but in the cell, not the VC: %@", [detailsViewController.finalURL absoluteString]);


}
```

Overview of the whole thing, where both the cell and url are being created (contains a snip it from above):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    PhotoCell *cell = (PhotoCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[PhotoCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    FeedEntity *feed = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSData *data = feed.imageData;

    NSData *stringData = feed.urlString;
    self.stringForURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:stringData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    self.stringForURL = [self.stringForURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Here is stringForURL: %@", self.stringForURL);
    self.finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.stringForURL];

//    self.detailsViewController.finalURL = self.finalURL;
    self.detailsViewController.path = self.path;
    //NSLog(@"Here is the url in other vc from one vc: %@", self.detailsViewController.finalURL);

    self.feedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    cell.thumbImage = self.feedImage;
    cell.finalURL = self.finalURL;
    NSLog(@"here is the URl in the cell: %@", [cell.finalURL absoluteString]);


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: NSData *stringData = feed.urlString; <-- What data type is urlString at this point? Without seeing the type, it seems like that's a string and you're trying to plop it into a data object. Double check in the debugger at every step along this way that the stringData and stringForURL look correct.

Comment: urlString is binary data @valheru

Comment: what does the strinForURL variable read out before you assign it to URLWithString?

Comment: So the self.final url in the view controller does is ok, it's just when I try to pass it to the cell it is null @valheru

Comment: How are you presenting the detailsViewController then? Currently you're allocating it and when the method ends, it will be deallocated.

Comment: So I have a custom cell and in that cell I have setUpCell among other things but inside the cell for some reason finalURL is null even before the setUpURL line. This is really strange because in the view controller it contains the url but in the cell, it is null @valheru

Comment: post some more code in relation to this?

Comment: This is pretty much all the code that relates to this, the only other thing inside the cell is the thumbnail which is working fine. It all seems like it should work but for some reason, the url must not be getting passed to the cell correctly because its fine in one view controller and null in the cell. Do you have any idea why this would be happening? @valheru

Comment: Where do you do `cell.finalURL = self.finalURL;`? How `finalURL` is declared in a cell?

Comment: I do it in cellForRowAtIndexPath, right bellow where I retrieve the url. I also added another line bellow that line which does print the url but when I go into the cell it is still nil! @flexaddicted

Comment: finalURL is declared as so `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *finalURL;`

Comment: Oh and here is the url in the view controller: file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/C9DAD987-AEBF-4FEA-ABFC-04121A72A84C/tmp‌​/capture/capturedvideo.MOV @valheru

Comment: I guess is something related to cell reuse. Please expand your question to add more details. Thanks.

Comment: Is the cell nil itself?

Comment: do you have any idea how I would fix this? @flexaddicted

Comment: The cells are all appearing correctly so I assume not @valheru

Comment: As @valheru suggested, check if the cell is null. You should provide some details in you answer. But no put all the code there.

Comment: where do you do `self.finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.stringForURL];`?

Comment: in cellForRowAtIndexPath @flexaddicted

Comment: What would be the best way to see if the cell is null? It is appearing and working so would assume it is not null

Comment: Provide code about cells creation...

Comment: I posted it the cellForRowAtIndexPath. @flexaddicted

Comment: Hey, I was just wondering if there was a different way I could accomplish what I am trying to do because the current way is still not working. @flexaddicted

Answer (score 0):

I would change a little bit the following code.

```
cell.thumbImage = [NSURL URLWithString:self.stringForURL];
cell.finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.stringForURL];
```

In fact you are using the same properties (`self.finalUrl`) and assign them to the cell url.

Now each cell would have the correct image and url.

In addition where do you call `setUpURL`?

Let me know if this solve your problem.

Comment: So for `cell.final` self.stringForURL has the url but then final URL in the cell is still null

Comment: Have you ever seen something like this?

Comment: @github The only manner to understand the problem is to debug. Otherwise you could extract a portion of your code and share it in github.

Comment: So the only problem I see is that it is not passing the url to the cell because the cell is fine in the viewController but not in the cell so I don't know how I can debug?

Comment: Oh, I've just thought of something, so when I nslog it all, the line that says the cell url is null comes before the one in the view controller, so I was thinking that maybe the URL was getting retrieved after the cell is created, thus it is null. I can't really think of any other reasons why it is null in the cell but not in the viewController

Comment: Log the url also in the second snippet posted in this question. Where do you call the setup url method? Could you edit your questio to have a complete understanding of your controller logic?

Comment: So currently, the setUp method doesn't have any chance of working because the url isn't being passed to the cell correctly so it has no url to pass on. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

From an MVC standpoint, you should not be storing any data in the cell. The cells are Views, and their purpose is to draw themselves onscreen. Similarly, you also should not be creating new viewControllers inside a cell, that is the job of a Controller (in this case, probably the tableViewDelegate).

Since you've already got Core Data set up, it might make sense to store your URL information in Core Data along with the pictures. When a table cell gets tapped and you need to pass information to the new viewController, you can use the indexPath tapped to determine the correct data to pass along.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers, I am pretty new to core data so what would this look like?